# Length of the longest substring -Given a string S, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: python

Why should we use a `max` function to update `start` when we can directly update `start` to `seen[S[i]]+1`

```
def longestUniqueSubsttr(self, S):
        # code here
        seen={}
        start=0
        max_len=0
        for i in range(len(S)):
            if S[i] in seen:
                #Why should we use a `max` function to update `start` when 
                #we can directly update `start` to `seen[S[i]]+1
                start=max(start,seen[S[i]]+1)
            seen[S[i]]=i
            max_len=max(max_len,i-start+1)
        return max_len
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why should we use a max function to update start when we can directly update start >to seen[S[i]]+1?

using a random string

```
S = 'zszhvbuthsjvkblsrrrrtttyyergsvkd'
seen={}
start=0
max_len=0
for i in range(len(S)):
    if S[i] in seen:
        start= max(start, seen[S[i]]+1)
    seen[S[i]]=i
    max_len=max(max_len,i-start+1)
print(max_len)
```

Output:

```
9
```

your 'start' value wont consider multiples of the same letter within the string if you dont use max. you wont start from the last repetition, but the first

```
S = 'zszhvbuthsjvkblsrrrrtttyyergsvkd'
seen={}
start=0
max_len=0
for i in range(len(S)):
   if S[i] in seen:
       start=  seen[S[i]]+1
   seen[S[i]]=i
   max_len=max(max_len,i-start+1)
print(max_len)
```

Output:

```
19
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would replace

```
start=max(start,seen[S[i]]+1)
```

by

```
start=seen[S[i]]+1
```

Then you will not always get the correct result. For example, for `S="abcaab"`, it will change the return value.

The reason is that `start` should only be allowed to increase, not decrease. If it is allowed to *decrease*, then a substring will be considered a candidate, when in fact it will have a duplicate character in it.

In the given example, this is what happens:

- When `i` is 3, the letter "a" is encountered as a duplicate, and `seen[S[i]] + 1` (which is `seen["a"] + 1`, which is 1) is assigned to `start`.
- When `i` is 4, the letter "a" is encountered again, and `seen[S[i]] + 1` (which is `seen["a"] + 1`, which is 4) is assigned to `start`.
- When `i` is 5, the letter "b" is encountered as a duplicate, and now `seen[S[i]] + 1` (which is `seen["b"] + 1`, which is 2) should *not be assigned* `start`, because the longest substring does not start after the first "b", but still after the first "a"!

This is the reason why you need the `max`.

Comment: how is "b" encounterd as duplicate when i=5 because the start is 4. the string is "ab" right?

Comment: When I say duplicate, I mean "b" is in `seen`, i.e. it had been encountered before (since index 0).